# Rotate a matrix array by 180 degrees?

Tags: javascript

I have a square matrix (might be even or odd nr of items per side) and I wish to rotate it 180 degrees. That is rotate, not flip.

I have found many rotation by 90 degrees of varying shape but no luck finding one for 180 degrees. My matrix could be very large to make doing 2x 90 degree runs unacceptable.

Comment: Why are you doing this? You just asked a question and answered it yourself.

Comment: @thefourtheye the website permits Q&A format which I took. You didn't have to downvote everything.

Comment: I promise. I didnt downvote any of your posts. You can check my profile for my downvotes.

Comment: You have quelled my thirst of vengeance, for now, @thefourtheye; but I promise you, when I find those response, there will be paint >:)

Answer (score 5):

Try the following:

```
grid.reverse().forEach(function(item) { item.reverse(); } );
console.log(grid);
```

Comment: Or, define `reversed(a)` as `a.slice(0).reverse()` and then `rotated = reversed(grid).map(reversed)`.